# Can you help me codding a new function to count the number of loops played?

Tags: javascript, loops, counting

This code is working perfectly (I love it) but I need to add another function to count the number of times the loop has been executed or the number of times the sound has been played. Can you help me? Thanks.

````
<html> 
<body> 

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio><br>

<button onclick="enableLoop()" type="button">Enable loop</button>
<button onclick="disableLoop()" type="button">Disable loop</button>
<button onclick="checkLoop()" type="button">Check loop status</button>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function enableLoop() { 
  x.loop = true;
  x.load();
} 

function disableLoop() { 
  x.loop = false;
  x.load();
} 

function checkLoop() { 
  alert(x.loop);
} 
</script> 

</body> 
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use audio element's events for doing that. In the below example I've linked to some static .mp3 file and added 'onseeking' event handler in which the number of start/resume is being counted. 
I've used specifically 'onseeking', because this event is fired when a seek operation starts and it covers the case of the loop play.

More on the events [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

```html
<html> 
<body> 

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio><br>

<button onclick="enableLoop()" type="button">Enable loop</button>
<button onclick="disableLoop()" type="button">Disable loop</button>
<button onclick="checkLoop()" type="button">Check loop status</button>
<button onclick="checkCount()" type="button">Check count</button>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var count = 0;
x.onseeking = (event) => {
  count++;
};

function enableLoop() { 
  x.loop = true;
  x.load();
} 

function disableLoop() { 
  x.loop = false;
  x.load();
} 

function checkLoop() { 
  alert(x.loop);
} 

function checkCount() { 
  alert(count);
} 
</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but I didn't find in the link you sent any solution for my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Viviane thank you. I've edited the answer and added 'Check count' which alerts current count. In the linked page please see 'Events' section, where all available events are listed - for my example 'seeking' is used.

Comment: Dear "user1987" thank you for your code. It works fine and I really thank you for your work. However to be completelly honest to you I want the counter to be visible in the console box and get rid of the unusefull time box. In other words, I would like to change the time box for a counter box. The sound will be much shorter, like a hotel porter bell. This is a school project that I have  to accomplish before the end of July. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to increment a counter within the last 0.25sec of the MP3 file duration time while playing. You'll need to:

- Register the `"timeupdate"` event to the `<audio>` tag.
- Get the MP3 file duration time with the `.duration` property.
- Monitor the progress with the `.currentTime` property.

---

#### Demo

**Note:** Details are commented in demo

```js
// Reference the <audio> tag
const mp3 = document.querySelector('audio');
// Reference the <form> tag
const ctrl = document.forms.controls;
// Collect all <output> and <button> into a HTML Collection
const ui = ctrl.elements;
// Define an external variable for a counter reference
let loops = 0;

/*
- Utility function to reset counter at a slight delay
*/
const counterReset = () => setTimeout(function() {
  ui.counter.value = '0';
  loops = 0;
}, 100);

/*
- Utility function to stop <audio> when playing
- There were multiple occurances of these 4 statements so
  this was made for the sake of DRY
*/
const stopPlay = () => {
  ui.playback.classList.add('play');
  ui.playback.classList.remove('pause');
  mp3.pause();
  mp3.currentTime = 0;
};

/*
- <audio> registered to the "timeupdate" event which is
  fired when playing at the frequenncy of 4 times a second
- So every 250ms event handler function countLoop is
  called during playback
*/
mp3.ontimeupdate = countLoop;

// <form> is registered to "click" and "reset" events
ctrl.onclick = playLoop;
ctrl.onreset = resetLoop;

// Click handler for <form>
function playLoop(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  let cmd = clicked.className;

  switch (cmd) {
    case 'play':
      clicked.classList.remove('play');
      clicked.classList.add('pause');
      mp3.play();
      break;
    case 'pause':
      clicked.classList.add('play');
      clicked.classList.remove('pause');
      mp3.pause();
      break;
    case 'loop':
      clicked.classList.add('once');
      clicked.classList.remove('loop');
      mp3.loop = true;
      stopPlay();
      counterReset();
      break;
    case 'once':
      clicked.classList.add('loop');
      clicked.classList.remove('once');
      mp3.loop = false;
      stopPlay();
      counterReset();
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

// Timeupdate handler for <audio>
function countLoop(event) {

  // Get the time of MP3 file
  let time = this.duration;
  
  /*
  - if [loop] is enabled AND the current time is more or
    equal to the difference of the duration of the MP3
    file and 0.3sec
  - Increment the counter in 0.15sec.
  - This odd delay pattern is to ensure that within the
    last 0.25sec of the MP3 file the counter will
    increment
  */
  if (this.loop && this.currentTime >= time - .3) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      loops++;
      ui.counter.value = loops
    }, 150);
    
  // Otherwise if the MP3 file ends, increment counter
  } else if (this.ended) {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    loops++;
    ui.playback.classList.add('play');
    ui.playback.classList.remove('pause');
  }
  ui.counter.value = loops;
}

// Reset Handler for <form>
function resetLoop(event) {
  stopPlay();
  counterReset();
}
```

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 400 4vh/1.5 Consolas;
}

output,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#counter {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 4rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0078D7;
}

#playback.play::before {
  content: '▶️'
}

#playback.pause::before {
  content: '⏸️'
}

#loopback.once::before {
  content: ''
}

#loopback.loop::before {
  content: ''
}
```

```html
<audio src='http://www.orangefreesounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Horse-trotting-sound.mp3?_=1'></audio>

<form id='controls'>
  <button id='playback' class='play' type='button'></button>
  <button type='reset'>⏹️</button>
  <button id='loopback' class='loop' type='button'></button>
  <output id='counter'>0</output>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you "zer00ne" for your code. Unfortunately it works on this platform but I can't make it work on my page, and I'm getting a little paranoid about my poor javascript  knowledge. But this was more or less what I wanted, a little box with the increasing counter while te sound was playing. Thank you, anyway. I will keep on trying.